# Installing Rails on Windows. "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation

I'm facing a problem when trying to install Rails on Windows 10.

Initially following installrails.com instructions and then a few other ideas in order to try and work around the problem, but still no joy.

I have the RailsInstaller installed.  I've used `curl http://installrails.com/update_rubygems.rb | ruby` to update the gems.

I then tried using `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc` to install Rails and I get

> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Have also tried just `gem install rails` and `sudo gem install rails --version 2.0`.  Also used `gem update --system 2.0.3` as I found this sometimes fixed the issue for others, however I'm getting the same error each time.

The full error message is:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/tools/ruby24/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/tools/ruby24/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:457:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:588:in `try_cpp'
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:1095:in `block in have_header'
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:945:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:944:in `checking_for'
        from C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:1094:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nio4r-2.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nio4r-2.1.0/ext/nio4r/gem_make.out
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like you're missing the development headers. Do you have a compiler installed? Base Windows is really a second-class citizen in the Ruby world, it's missing a lot of things POSIX systems take for granted. The good news is that the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can give you an environment a lot more like Ubuntu which may resolve problems like this by providing a rich suite of tools.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I probably don't have a compiler installed as I'm very new to development tbh. If this could resolve the problem, are you able to recommend a good compiler I could install?

Comment: I'm not sure what makes Windows happy other than the Windows Subsystem for Linux if that's an option.

Comment: Thanks tadman, will give that a go then!  Will let you know if it works.

Comment: I've managed to now fix the issue. Basically I had downloaded and installed the MSYS2 DevKit but wasn't aware that I then needed to run "ridk install" in the command line to make it work.

In case anyone else is having this issue, there is a good walk through on https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2.

Comment: It's worth adding that as a self-answer here to help others in the same jam. Adding an answer marks this question as answered.